# too many threads due to synch communication

Tags: python, multithreading, xml-rpc

I'm using threads and xmlrpclib in python at the same time. Periodically, I create a bunch of thread to complete a service on a remote server via xmlrpclib. The problem is that, there are times that the remote server doesn't answer. This causes the thread to wait forever for a response which it never gets. Over time, number of threads in this state increases and will reach the maximum number of allowed threads on the system (I'm using fedora). 
I tried to use socket.setdefaulttimeout(10); but the exception that is created by that will cause the server to defunct. I used it at server side but it seems that it doesn't work :/

Any idea how can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing what I usually call (originally in Spanish xD) "happy road programming". You should implement your programs to handle undesired cases, not only the ones you want to happen.

The threads here are only showing an underlying mistake: your server can't handle a timeout, and the implementation is rigid in a way that adding a timeout causes the server to crash due to an unhandled exception.

Implement it more robustly: it must be able to withstand an exception, servers can't die because of a misbehaving client. If you don't fix this kind of problem now, you may have similar issues later on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your real problem is that the server hangs on certain requests, *and* dies if the client closes the socket - the threads are just a side effect of the implementation. If I'm understanding what you're saying correctly, then the only way to fix this would be to fix the server to respond to all requests, or to be more robust with network failure, or (preferably) both.